# How to retrieve column items from listview in code

Tags: wpf, vb.net, listview, datagrid

I am new to wpf and am going for an MCTS exam. I have searched for 2 days now on how to retrieve row column items in code. I have been able to insert data into the listview by creating a structure and adding row items via code.

```
Public Structure SimpleData
    Public Property Txt1 As String
        Get
            Return mTxt1
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            mTxt1 = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private mTxt1 As String
    Public Property Txt2 As String
        Get
            Return mTxt2
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            mTxt2 = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private mTxt2 As String
    Public Property Txt3 As String
        Get
            Return mTxt3
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            mTxt3 = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private mTxt3 As String
End Structure
Public Structure MyData
    Public Property Desc() As String
        Get
            Return m_Desc
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Desc = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Desc As String
    Public Property Progress() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_Progress
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            m_Progress = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Progress As Integer
    Public Property ProgressText() As String
        Get
            Return m_ProgressText
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_ProgressText = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_ProgressText As String
    Public Property Pic() As String
        Get
            Return m_Pic
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Pic = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Pic As String
End Structure

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim sd As New SimpleData
    sd.Txt1 = "Today is"
    sd.Txt2 = "a good day"
    sd.Txt3 = "O YES!"
    listView1.Items.Add(sd)
End Sub
```

I want to be able to retrieve row(0).Item(0).ToString, which is how to retrieve it in win forms. Expecting a response. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer by casting the listview item to the created structure SimpleData then looping through it

```
        Dim getitems = CType(listView1.SelectedItem, SimpleData)
        For Each mem In getitems.Txt1
            MsgBox(mem.ToString)
        Next
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            Dim constr As String = "Put your connection string here"
            Dim ds As New DataSet
            Dim con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(constr)
            con.Open()
            Dim sqladap As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("select * from tbl_Employee", con)
            sqladap.Fill(ds)

            For i As Integer = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
                ListView1.Columns.Add(ds.Tables(0).Columns(i).ToString())
            Next
            For i As Integer = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
                Dim listRow As New ListViewItem
                listRow.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)(0).ToString()
                For j As Integer = 1 To ds.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
                    listRow.SubItems.Add(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)(j).ToString())
                Next
                ListView1.Items.Add(listRow)
            Next

Read data  from Listview :

Dim name, room, subject, date, period As String
If listviewName.SelectedItems.Count > 0 then
    For i As Integer = 0 To listviewName.SelectedItems.Count - 1
        '*********** transfer selected data on declare String variable ************'
        name= listviewName.SelectedItems(i).SubItems(0).Text
        room = listviewName.SelectedItems(i).SubItems(1).Text
        subject = listviewName.SelectedItems(i).SubItems(2).Text
        date= listviewName.SelectedItems(i).SubItems(3).Text
        period= listviewName.SelectedItems(i).SubItems(4).Text
        '*********** delete **************'
        cmd1.Connection = MYSQLCON
        MYSQLCON.Open()
        cmd1.CommandText = "DELETE FROM tablename WHERE columnname = '" & name & "'"
        reader = cmd1.ExecuteReader
        MYSQLCON.Close()
   Next
End If
```

Comment: i am feeding the listview through texts from my textboxes, now i want to add the items to my database. I tried to do something like this: Dim lv as new listitemview lv = listview1.items msgbox lv.items(0).Subitem(1).ToString but the intellisense rejects it

Comment: I was able to find the items by casting the listview.selecteditems to the structure SimpleDate and selecting it using loop.                                                              Dim getitems = CType(listView1.SelectedItem, SimpleData)
            For Each mem In getitems.Txt1
                MsgBox(mem.ToString)
            Next